# Can I distribute a python application with docker?

Tags: python, docker

I am developing a python application (a package) that can be distributed with distutils. 
I need to share it with someone that does not have python installed.

Is it possible to bundle the entire package and distribute it with docker?

Comment: What if they don't have Docker installed? Or are you planning to distribute the whole Docker alongside?

Comment: I know for a fact they have docker but unsure they have python or the correct version of python.

Comment: then you could distribute a Docker container with Python no problem. Although it'd probably be easier to make an executable out of your Python code (with Py2exe / Py2app or something similar).

Answer (score 4):

If they have docker then you can distribute your whole application as a docker image. This is the main docker use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can distribute the app through an image in a registry. Given your description and comments, it sounds like [Docker Cloud](https://cloud.docker.com) would be a good place to do that. Cloud is the more modern interface to Docker Hub. Then they can just do a `docker pull yourusername/yourimagename` and use the app. And they don't have to have python installed.